# How do you update a node/minion's label in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Anyone out there who succesfully updated a node/minion's label in Kubernetes? I can't seem to find any documentation for it.

I tried:

`kubectl update -f minion.yaml` with a template gotten from `kubectl get minion 192.168.0.102 -o yaml`. I get the following error:

```
minion "192.168.0.102" is invalid: status: invalid value '{HostIP:192.168.0.102 Phase: Conditions:[{Kind:Ready Status:Full LastTransitionTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Reason: Message:}]}': status must be empty
```

I tried removing the status from the minion.yaml file - to no avail. The API version of the minion is v1beta1.

I see there is a [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/2406) regarding documentation for this capability. I assume you use nodeSelector and minion labels to "pin a pod to a specific machine".

Thanks.

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also need to remove HostIP field for your commands to work (apart from just status).  Internally, kubernetes treats HostIP as a status field.

This is a conversion problem in v1beta1/2.  The problem will be temporarily fixed in next release, and we are looking into a long term solution.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the Containers at Google Group we are working on adding an edit-label command to kubectl. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-containers/VFYl5HJFM2s

Cheers,

Satnam